# Unmarshal data stream according to rule file in python

Tags: python, templates, data-structures, stream

I have a data file which has written data (which forms a data of C++ structure from an application). Now I am using python to read this data file. What is the best way to provide this structure as a input template and then have a logic to read based on this template.

Idea is that if the structure (in my C++ application changes) then for script to maintain compatibility, I would like to change the template and no other change should suffice me with the data read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd declare ctypes.Struct classes in Python as templates, and then use the regular ctypes functions to marshal and unmarshal from byte arrays to structs.

Comment: Only answer I got :). I will  try it, hope it works with ease. Thanks!